# For Question About a Warning In Objective-c Coding

Tags: iphone

I have one file viewcontroller.h and .m and viewcontroller1.h and .m

In viewcontroller1.m file ,
i write function like BOOL rechable = [viewcontroller functionrechable];

it gives me warning like   warning:initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast

how   to  remove  this   warning???
is it any way to  do it?

Comment: What is the type of viewcontroller? And what is a return type of functionrechable?

Comment: NSObject class is for viewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

This is telling you that your defining reachable as a BOOL type which really resolves to an integer typye, yet the [viewcontroller functionrechable] message is returning a pointer.  You can remove the warning either by casting the return type of the function to BOOL or int, or changing the type of reachable to a pointer.

Comment: Yes, odds are that he's returning an NSNumber from that method, rather than a boolean value.  In that case, calling boolValue on the result of the method should do the trick.

Comment: if anyone cares, BOOL is a signed char on the iPhone

Answer (score 0):

What is the definition for the method [viewcontroller functionrechable]....

The solution is most likely:

```
BOOL rechable = (BOOL) [viewcontroller functionrechable];
```

But I would need the definition to be sure.